# Get property value of instance of generic type's argument

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Using reflection:

If I have an instance of type `X<Y>` (I don't know what `Y` is exactly) since `X` is a generic type (`X<T>`), how do I get the value of a property on `Y`?

Something like:

```
Type yType = currentObject.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

// How do I get yInstance???
var yInstance = Convert.ChangeType(???, yType);
```

I need to get to:

```
object requiredValue = yType.GetProperty("YProperty").GetValue(yInstance, null);
```

Comment: That would depend on what `X` is and how it is related to `Y`.  e.g., If `X` was a collection, then `Y` would probably be an item in that collection.

Comment: X is a custom class type and Y is also a custom class type.

Comment: Again, _how are they related?_ Is there a property of `X` that gives you a `Y`? Does a property of `X` have a property that has a property of type `Y`? _Again_, it depends on how they are related to each other.

Comment: X is a different class and Y is a different class. X has its own properties and Y has its own properties. Perhaps something like: Car<Blue>, Car<Red>, etc. The Blue, Red are types of Y while Car is the X. All the Y types might have some common properties (for example color) but will also have additional specific properties.

Answer (score 2):

Get the PropertyInfo object for the generic argument using:

```
PropertyInfo myProperty = myGenericType.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0].GetProperty("myPropertyName");
```

where "0" is the index of the generic type in the class definition and "myPropertyName" is the name of the property. After that, use it as you would any other PropertyInfo object, for example:

```
myProperty.GetValue(obj); // Where obj is an instance of the generic type
```

[Edit: original answer below]

If Y must have a property, constrain the type T to one that must implement an interface that contains that property. For example:

```
public class MyGenericClass<Y> where Y:IMyInterface
```

Then cast the generic object to the interface and call the property.

Comment: Unfortunately cant do that. There is already an interface for Y and already have a set of common properties. But I need a property that is specific to a type of Y which is not in the interface.

Comment: Thanks but different Y types will have different sets of properties. So I cant use the interface.

Comment: @user1647697 I updated the answer to also say how to do it without using an interface. Please let me know if the new answer fixes your issue.

Comment: Hmm. I am wondering where you got object from in: myProperty.GetValue(object);

Comment: @user1647697 It is an object of the generic type. For example, if your generic type is a List<Y>, it's an element of the list of type Y. A you probably know, you get the property signature and metadata from the type and the value from objects of that type.

Comment: The problem here is that the X is not a list. So I cannot get an item from the list to get an instance of the Y. Look at the above comment where I talked about Cars in different colors. So the instance I have is currentObject as I mentioned in my original post and its of type X<Y>. I am unable to get the instance of Y. If I can get to that I have no issues retrieving the property of it.

Comment: Following the above example, if you are implementing the Car class, either instantiate a new instance of Y and call the property on it (you may want to add were Y:new() to guarantee a argumentless constructor) or require it to be passed in to the Car constructor. Is that closer to what you are asking?

Comment: I can do that but then that would be a new instance of Y but not the original instance which has some properties set!

Comment: Then pass the value in to the constructor of via a method as the previous comment suggested. Forget about it being a generic type. Think how you would implement it as a nongeneric type and do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I ended up passing in the X<Y> to a static method in the X class. Also passed in the property name whose value I wanted to retrieve. The static method can handle it best since its the same class. Finally got it working! Thanks for your time. Appreciate it.