# Get value from property on generic class using open definition

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Is there a way to get the value of a property from an open type using reflection?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var target = new GenericType<string>();
        target.GetMe = "GetThis";
        target.DontCare = "Whatever";

        var prop = typeof(GenericType<>).GetProperty("GetMe");
        var doesntWork = prop.GetValue(target);
    }
}

public class GenericType<T>
{
    public string GetMe { get; set; }
    public T DontCare { get; set; }
}
```

`prop.GetValue(target)` throws the following exception:

> Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.

I know I can just do `target.GetType().GetProperty("GetMe").GetValue(target)`, but I want to know if there's a way to get the value without knowing the type.

The simple solution would be to have a non-generic base class that just contains `GetMe`, but I can't make that change right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I would just avoid reflection all together and use the [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) Keyword for scenarios like this.

```
var val = ((dynamic)target).GetMe;
```

but if you really want to use reflection, the following will work.

```
var val = typeof(GenericType<string>).GetProperty("GetMe").GetValue(target);
```

Comment: The generic type argument will differ based on context, so the second option doesn't work.  However, the `dynamic` option is exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is that your `typeof(GenericType<>)` creates a `Type` object which represents an incomplete type. You can only get values using a complete type object.

You need to obtain a complete type object first. Since you already have an object to work on, you could just use the type from that object

```
    var prop = target.GetType().GetProperty("GetMe");
    var doesWork = prop.GetValue(target);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `typeof(GenericType<>)`, you doesn't provide a `T` parameter to your type, so the runtime can't get value of a property.
You need to use `.GenericTypeArguments[0]` here, like this:

```
var prop = typeof(GenericType<>).GenericTypeArguments[0].GetProperty("GetMe");
```

See original post to futher information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12273584/213550

Comment: The link addresses getting the type from an object rather than using `typeof`; it does not work in this situation.  There are no `GenericTypeArguments` when getting the open type.

Comment: Only if you do it on the closed/fully-defined type.  `typeof(GenericType<>)` is not the same thing as `((GenericType<string>)myVar).GetType()`.